# How to add mega repo in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, aur, synclient

How can I add the Mega repository to Arch Linux?

Already add this in my `pacman.conf`

```
[DEB_Arch_Extra]
SigLevel = Required TrustedOnly
Server = https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Arch_Extra/$arch
```

But I am getting this error:

```
❯ nocorrect sudo pacman -Syyu
[sudo] password for scarlet:
error: DEB_Arch_Extra: signature from "MegaLimited <support@mega.co.nz>" is unknown trust
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 kde-unstable                                                     122.0 KiB  74.2 KiB/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
 gnome-unstable                                                    45.0   B   109   B/s 00:00 [#######################################################] 100%
 core                                                             136.5 KiB   136 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################################] 100%
 extra                                                           1569.9 KiB   716 KiB/s 00:02 [#######################################################] 100%
 community                                                          5.8 MiB  1737 KiB/s 00:03 [#######################################################] 100%
 multilib                                                         148.2 KiB   136 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################################] 100%
 archzfs                                                           14.1 KiB  16.4 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################################] 100%
 DEB_Arch_Extra                                                     3.1 KiB  2.51 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################################] 100%
error: DEB_Arch_Extra: signature from "MegaLimited <support@mega.co.nz>" is unknown trust
error: failed to synchronize all databases (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))                                                            /17.4s
```

My system:

```
❯ uname -a
Linux lenovo 5.15.3-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 18 Nov 2021 22:23:08 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux                                                            /0.1s
```

What I have tried:

- I found this [issue-with-signature-from-mega-deb-arch-extra-fails-to-update](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/issue-with-signature-from-mega-deb-arch-extra-fails-to-update/70433) but I can't try the suggested solution since I can't install Manjaro keys on my Arch system (or can I? I am not sure): This is [possible solution suggested](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/failed-to-update-deb-arch-extra-invalid-or-corrupted-database-pgp-signature/48057/14)
- don't want to use AUR because it fails to build
- the binary AUR though installs successfully lacks plugins support
- plugins in separate AUR are outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by running the following commands

```
curl -fsSL https://mega.nz/keys/MEGA_signing.key | pacman-key --add -

pacman-key --finger 7F068E5D

pacman-key --lsign-key 7F068E5D

pacman -Syyu
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `SigLevel` to `Never` or `Optional TrustAll`.

Comment: thanks for the reply , that might be a solution but since the repo itself contains .sig files i think this should work without changing SigLevel {am not sure though}